# JPA Hibernate limit recursion, json jackson breadth first

Tags: java, json, hibernate, jpa, jackson

I have a Abstract base class "BaseArticle"

I use the scheme of having a table for each different class.

I have two classes extending this:

```
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@JsonIdentityInfo(
          generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, 
          property = "id")
@Entity
public class ArticleA extends BaseArticle {
    ....
}

@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@JsonIdentityInfo(
          generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, 
          property = "id")
    @Entity
public class ArticleB extends BaseArticle {
    ....
}
```

(These have the inheritance attribute, cause they can also get extended, it's a bit more complex, but I'm just trying to highlight the issue)

now my base article looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@JsonIdentityInfo(
          generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, 
          property = "id")
public abstract class BaseArticle  implements Serializable{
    ...
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    public Long id;

        @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinTable(name="recommendedarticle",
        joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="baseart_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="recommended_id")})
    @Size(min=0, max=6)
    @ElementCollection(targetClass=BaseArticle.class)
    public Set<BaseArticle> recommended;

    public Set<BaseArticle> getRecommended() {
        return recommended;
    }

    public void setRecommended(Set<BaseArticle> recommended) {
        this.recommended = recommended;
    }
}
```

Now, I created the functions just to test if this would fix stuff, so it's currently a bit untidy.

But the issue is, an article has multiple articles that can be recommended with it.

I've ran into the following issues:

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(
          generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, 
          property = "id")
```

I've found this through the Docs, that this would make sure multiple articles wouldn't be loaded and cause cycles or errors, however this is a depth first way: the first article gets loaded, then the recommended of the first, then the recommended of the first recommended in that article, which leaves the output json like this:

```
[
  {
     title:"Article1",
     "recommended":[
        art2,art3, etc.
     ]
   }, 
   IDOFArt2,
   IDOFArt3,
   etc..
]
```

So the issue is, it's doing depth first instead of breadth first. which is my first problem.
The second problem is (which can also easily fix the first), I don't need the recommended articles of the recommended articles. Is there a way to limit this "depth" in json?

Comment: First select the article and its recommendations, then put nulls (or empty lists) for the recommended articles of recommended articles. Otherwise, create a DTO that isn't infinitely recursive.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work for the json even though it's a lot of custom code. I had hoped there would be a solution in the library. This doesn't stop Hibernate from loading all the entities I believe? I really want the first set eagerly loaded, but ofcourse not the rest.

Comment: Hibernate should only load what you tell it to load, at least assuming it is not EAGER loading. Personally I recommend against EAGER loading for these sorts of reasons. If lazy loaded, then the query is an article and a self join for the recommended articles. Best thing is DTO's between the interfaces and the data layer. More code, perhaps, but the extra control is worth it.